# How to make console display chess symbols

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, chess

I looked on other posts on this site on how to display unicode in the cmd prompt but my problem is that even when I have:

```
 Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        Console.WriteLine("♔");
        Console.WriteLine("♕");
```

It displays the White king&queen as something like the following Róo (King) and Roò (Queen). (In terminal)

Is there anything I can do to make the king&queen display properly?

Comment: Change your console font to one that actually supports those characters?

Comment: You should read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Did you follow the advice in "Notes to Callers"?

Comment: What actually is your console? If it's something like PuTTY you need to make sure it's configured to treat incoming data as UTF-8.

Comment: Did you get this to work?